# I try to get information from login form and change it to the id

Tags: javascript, java, html

I have a login page in html that i get there username, password and type
and when i log in to the account i need to find the account details from the id of the user get when he register, but every time i get this message that it cannot convert from: "'java.lang.String' to required type 'long'"; how can i fix this?
my login method return long which is the id type.

this is the code:

```
public class LoginController {

    @Autowired
    LoginServiceImpl loginService;

    @GetMapping("/login/{userName}/{password}/{clientType}")
    public long Login(@PathVariable("userName") String userName,@PathVariable("password") String password,
            @PathVariable("clientType") ClientType clientType)throws CustomException {
        return loginService.login(userName, password, clientType);}
```

---

```
public long login(String userName, String password, ClientType clientType) throws CustomException {
    if(clientType.equals(ClientType.ADMIN)) {
        adminService.login(userName, password, clientType);
        System.out.println("admin loged in");

    }
    else if(clientType.equals(ClientType.COMPANY)) {
        Company companyLogin = companyRepository.findByCompName(userName);
        companyService.login(userName, password, clientType);
        System.out.println("company loged in");
        return companyLogin.getId();
    }
    else if(clientType.equals(ClientType.CUSTOMER)) {
        customerService.login(userName, password, clientType);
        System.out.println("customer loged in");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("login didnt execute");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

```
    $scope.submit=function(){
$http.get("http://localhost:8080/rest/api/login/" +     $scope.username +"/" + $scope.password + "/" + $scope.cType).then(
    function(response){
        $scope.login = response.data;
        switch ($scope.cType){


            case "COMPANY":
                window.location.assign("http://localhost:8080/rest/api/company.html")
                break;
```

---

```
                $scope.hideAllTables();
                $scope.welcomePage = true;
                // $scope.MainMenu = true;
                $http.get('http://localhost:8080/rest/api/company.html/comanyDetailes/' + compny).then(function(response) {
                            $scope.company = response.data;
                            $scope.welcomePage = true;
                        }, function(error) {
                            alert('operation failed ', error.data);
                        });
```